# how to manage timer in a Service to run in background

Tags: android, android-studio, service, timer

I am Trying to Implement a service where when I a select a time, the timer starts and runs in the background. the thing is working fine. but when I select another time, the timer overlaps on one another. I want my app to work in such a way that different services should run for different time. also, when I kill the app and reopen it, I get the remaining time in all the services.

however my data is coming from a web service and this web service contains a field with time. when I click the time, the above concept should start.

I have implemented my code as,

BroadCastService.java

```
public class BroadCastService extends Service {

private long totalTimeCountInMilliseconds;
private long timeBlinkInMilliseconds;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private boolean blink;
String getTime;

public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "project.uop.assignment8";
Intent bi = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);

public BroadCastService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    getTime = intent.getStringExtra("time");
    setTimer();
    startTimer();
    Log.i("madhura","madhura");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

private void setTimer() {
    int time = 0;
   //if (getTime.equals("")) {
        time = Integer.parseInt(getTime);
  //  } else
       /* Toast.makeText(BroadCastService.this, "Please Enter Minutes...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

    totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = 60 * time * 1000;

    timeBlinkInMilliseconds = 30 * 1000;
}



private void startTimer() {
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 500) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
            long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;

            if (leftTimeInMilliseconds < timeBlinkInMilliseconds) {
                if (blink) {
                   // mTextField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // if blink is true, textview will be visible
                } else {
                 //   mTextField.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                blink = !blink;
            }

            String a = String.format("%02d", seconds / 60) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds % 60);
            bi.putExtra("countdown", a);
            sendBroadcast(bi);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Toast.makeText(BroadCastService.this, "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }.start();
}
```

}

and my TimerActivity.class

```
public class TimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView mTextField;
TextView hotel;
private long totalTimeCountInMilliseconds;
private long timeBlinkInMilliseconds;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private boolean blink;
String getTime;
SessionManager sessionManager;
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
    InitializeToolbar();
    Intent in = getIntent();
    getTime = in.getStringExtra("time");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,BroadCastService.class);
    intent.putExtra("time",getTime);
    this.startService(intent);
    sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
    hotel = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    hotel.setText(sessionManager.getUserName());
    Log.i("started", "Started service");
    mTextField = findViewById(R.id.timer);
}

public void InitializeToolbar(){
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Order Notification");
}



private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateGUI(intent); // or whatever method used to update your GUI fields
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(BroadCastService.COUNTDOWN_BR));
    Log.i("efgh", "Registered broacast receiver");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(br);
    Log.i("abcd", "Unregistered broadcast receiver");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Receiver was probably already stopped in onPause()
    }
    super.onStop();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopService(new Intent(this, BroadCastService.class));
    Log.i("Stopped", "Stopped service");
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void updateGUI(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
        String millisUntilFinished = intent.getStringExtra("countdown");
        mTextField.setText(millisUntilFinished);
    }
}
```

}

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Handler` and `@Overide` its method `Handler#handleMessage(Message msg)`

See this: https://gist.github.com/mjohnsullivan/403149218ecb480e7759

Comment: Welcome :)@Madhura